# Anyone have experience integrating datadog monitoring with Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datadog

Does anyone know if Datadog agent works on snowflake? We want to use Datadog to collect snowflake metrics, traces and logs and create dashboards, graphs, and monitors.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install the Datadog agent on a Snowflake host.

We use our separate job scheduling system to monitor Snowflake by running queries (e.g. checks on SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_DEPTH, aggregate queries against the QUERY_HISTORY for timing, etc) via the JDBC connector then relaying the results to our monitoring stack (similar to how Datadog agent would work.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `datadog-agent` either on an AWS EC2 instance or Azure Compute Instance. You will need a technical user with appropriate roles to do the monitoring on Snowflake. Configure the agent with the Snowflake details and you can then perform the monitoring.

Check out this official [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/snowflake/) to learn more.